# d3 selection from HtmlElement

Tags: typescript, d3.js

How do you get a d3 selection from a single HTMLElement?

Handing an element actually selects multiple in my case

```
someCallback((element : HTMLElement) => {
    d3.select(element).attr('fill', '#00ff00');
}
```

The above example changes the color of all my rects, not only the one

Comment: That looks like it should work. Are you sure the element is a `rect` and not a `g`?

Comment: On which elements do you actually call `someCallback()`? Can you set up a [mcve]? Why do you think multiple elements might be selected? There is a difference between selecting multiple elements and having an effect on multiple elements.

Comment: What happens if you just use `element.setAttribute('fill', '#00ff00');`

Comment: The @SmokeyShakers suggestion looks a reasonable one. Can you just print `console.log('Element: ', element.tagName);` before `d3.select...` line?

Comment: Found out something interesting. I had copied five rects with all identical properties. Turns out d3 can't tell them apart. Changed one digit on the x/y coordinates or fill color and it works. Maybe a SVG DOM issue? Anyways, the above example works given that elements are in some way unique...